# deleting from localStorage deletes multiple instances

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm Attempting an exercise involving the concept of localStorage in JS.

The exercise involves taking user input of their favourite songs and adding it to localStorage and displaying the data on the DOM.

The requirements are to add a song and display this individually on the page, and then delete an instance of each song from the localStorage and the subsequently from the webpage.

I'm having challenges actually deleting the song from the localStorage -- if I click on the delete button -- it should delete that instance of the song from the localStorage array and the DOM BUT it actually deletes 2 or more objects from the arrays on of Songs I have in localStorage.

I've tried everything I could think of (loops, trying to remove the song using the index) and would love advice on how to solve this issue. I've shared the JS code and user interface for your perusal.

```js
JAVASCRIPT CODE
//Retrieving all the elements
let artistName = document.getElementById("artistName");
let songTitle = document.getElementById("title");
let albumTitle = document.getElementById("album");
let yearReleased = document.getElementById("rel-year");

//Initiated an empty array to store all songs
let songArray = [];

function pageLoad() {
if (localStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
localStorage.setItem("songs", JSON.stringify(songArray));
localStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
} else {
//Using a forEach loop to loop through the songArray to populate the song data on the webpage
let songContainer = document.getElementById("song-display-container");
songContainer.innerHTML = "";
songArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("songs"));
songArray.forEach(function (song, index) {
let songDisplay = document.createElement("div");
songDisplay.setAttribute("id", "song-display");
songDisplay.innerHTML =
<h2>Song: ${song.songTitle}</h2>
<ul>
<li>Artist: ${song.artist}</li>
<li>Album: ${song.albumTitle}</li>
<li>Release Year: ${song.releaseYear}</li>
<li>Genre: ${song.musicGenre}</li>
</ul>;
songContainer.appendChild(songDisplay);

  //Code to delete the song from DOM and localStorage
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
  btn.innerHTML = "Delete";
  songDisplay.appendChild(btn);
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    //Deleting song entry from the DOM
    let songItem = event.target;
    songItem.parentElement.remove();
    //Deleting song entry from local storage
    songArray.splice(index);
    localStorage.setItem("songs", JSON.stringify(songArray));
  });
});
}
}

/ADDING A NEW SONG TO [SONG ARRAY] AND LOCAL STORAGE/
//Used the constructor function to create the Song class with properties.
function Song(aName, title, album, relYear, genre) {
this.artist = aName;
this.songTitle = title;
this.albumTitle = album;
this.releaseYear = relYear;
this.musicGenre = genre;
}

//Function to add to new song object to the songArray and localStorage.
function addSong() {
let musicGenre = document.getElementById("genre-select");
songArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("songs"));
let newSong = new Song(
artistName.value,
songTitle.value,
albumTitle.value,
yearReleased.value,
musicGenre.value
);
songArray.push(newSong);
localStorage.setItem("songs", JSON.stringify(songArray));
pageLoad();
}

//CLEAR LOCAL STORAGE
function clearLS() {
localStorage.clear();
}
`
```

[image]

Comment: Good first attempt, but... The title should give a summary of the (specific) problem. The snippet should be executable and provide relevant information (your snippet is missing the markup/HTML part). It also shouldn't add additional errors (like those syntax errors) that are not in your actual code. If you use a snippet (which is a good thing) please also use its _"Tidy"_ feature for proper formatting of the code in it. And don't post images of code, errors, or other relevant data - and especially not of things that don't add anything useful to the question -> [ask]

Comment: Thank you Andreas - I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `splice` function without a second argument, which will delete every element from the index until the end of the array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: So its just a typo because its explained in the documentation of `.splice()`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Evert - I've tried that as well -- but I get the result where at first deletion of any song (btn click) it removes 2 objects in the array. This was the code --- .splice(index, 1). to remove one array item at a time.